# How can I limit input number?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I want to limit the number to be lower than or equal to 65535 when I input  number. When I calculate sum of two numbers in asssembly, emu8086 can not calculate sum of number higher than 65535, so I want to limit input to lower than or equal to 65535.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
 tb1 db 10,13,"Input first number: $"
 tb2 db 10,13,"Input second number: $"
 tb3 db 10,13,"Sum of two number:$"
 tb4 db 10,13,"Invalid number. Please input again: $"
 
 x dw ?
 y dw ?
 z dw ?
 t dw ?
 k dw ?
 
.code
main proc
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    
    ;input first number
    mov ah,9
    lea dx,tb1
    int 21h
    
    call input_number
    mov ax,x
    mov z,ax
    
    ;input second number
    mov ah,9
    lea dx,tb2
    int 21h
    
    call input_number
    mov ax,x
    mov t,ax
    
    ;in tong 2 so
    mov ah,9
    lea dx,tb3
    int 21h
    
    mov ax,x
    add ax,t
    jc overflow_number
    
    overflow_number:
        mov ax,z
        xor cx,cx
        xor dx,dx
        mov bx,10
        div bx
        
        mov x,ax
        mov k,dx
        
        mov ax,t
        xor cx,cx
        xor dx,dx
        mov bx,10
        div bx
        
        add x,ax ;cong 2 so sau khi chia 10
        add dx,k ;cong so du
        mov k,dx
        cmp k,9
        jl show
        cmp k,9
        jg reminder
        
    reminder:
        mov ax,k
        xor cx,cx
        xor dx,dx
        mov bx,10
        div bx
        add ax,dx
        inc x
        mov k,ax
        dec k
    
    show:
        mov ax,x
        mov x,ax
        call print
        mov ax,k
        mov x,ax
        call print    
    
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

main endp
;ham con

;input function
input_number proc
    mov x,0
    mov y,0
    mov bx,10
    mov cx,5
    
        input:
            mov ah,1
            int 21h
     
            cmp al,13
            je sumbit
            
            cmp al,30h
            jb invalid_number
            cmp al,39h
            ja invalid_number
            
            sub al,30h
            xor ah,ah
            mov y,ax
            mov ax,x
            mul bx
            add ax,y
            mov x,ax
            loop input    
            
            
        sumbit:
            ret
            
        invalid_number:
            mov ah,9
            lea dx,tb4
            int 21h
            jmp main proc


input_number endp

;print function

print proc
    mov ax,x
    mov bx,10
    mov cx,0
    
        divide:
            mov dx,0
            div bx 
            push dx 
            inc cx 
            cmp ax,0 
            je hienthi 
            jmp divide 
                      
        hienthi:      
            pop dx
            add dl,30h
            mov ah,2
            int 21h
            dec cx
            cmp cx,0
            jne hienthi
            ret
    
    
        
print endp


end main
```

Comment: In `input_number` after `mul bx` use `test dx, dx` then `jnz ...` to check for the multiplication overflowing 16 bits, and after `add ax, y` add a `jc ...` to check for adding the digit overflowing 16 bits. Also, your `jc overflow_number` instruction is useless because you proceed to the same code regardless of whether the CY condition is true or false.

Comment: Before your `invalid_number` branch as in `jmp main proc` you should add a `pop ...` instruction to discard the near return address off the stack. Otherwise a user could overflow your stack if they enter many invalid numbers.

Comment: @ecm According to https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul.html , `MUL` already sets `OF` and `CF` if DX is non-zero, so the `TEST` instruction can be omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> mov ax,x
> add ax,t
> jc overflow_number
>
> overflow_number:
> ```

This is a problematic part of you program!

- Adding the *x* and *t* variables will just be doubling the second inputted number, since the last interactions with these particular variables were `mov ax,x` `mov t,ax` (`x=t`). You should have writen: `mov ax,z` `add ax,t`.
- Even if the addition does not produce a set carry, the execution will always continue with the code that deals with overflow (either by jumping to it or falling through)
- I don't understand at all what it is you want to do when overflow happens.

---

Confining the input to the range [0,65535] is easy:

```
input_number proc
    mov  x, 0
    mov  cx, 5
  input:
    mov  ah, 01h
    int  21h           ; -> AL
    cmp  al, 13
    je   sumbit
    sub  al, 30h
    cmp  al, 9
    ja   invalid_number ; Not a decimal digit
    xor  ah, ah
    mov  bx, ax         ; -> BX is NewDigit
    mov  ax, 10
    mul  x
    jc   invalid_number ; Out of range
    add  ax, bx
    jc   invalid_number ; Out of range
    mov  x, ax
    loop input    
  sumbit:
    ret
  invalid_number:
    mov  dx, OFFSET tb4
    mov  ah, 09h
    int  21h
    pop  ax             ; Forget `call input_number`
    jmp  main           ; (*)
input_number endp
```

(*) Does emu8086 accept `jmp  main proc` ?

Comment: I notice that you have appreciated [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75848842/i-want-to-input-string-from-keyboard-and-reverse-this-string-the-input-string-c/75849854#75849854). Could you please consider clicking the accept arrow to the left of the answer *if the answer solved your problem satisfactory*.